# Android VerticalViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter fragment positions

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using [VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager/blob/master/library/src/main/java/fr/castorflex/android/verticalviewpager/VerticalViewPager.java) by castorflex, but it seems to be the same as a usual ViewPager.

It shows wrong positions on changing scroll direction.

The point is that:

I scroll several pages down and have positions 0->1->2->3->4->5. Then I scroll upwards and suddenly the position of the new page is 2.

1. The positions shown in a TextView in fragments are correct.
2. The positions written to the log or to an external file are wrong.
3. The old and new positions obtained from **OnPageChangeListener** written to the log are correct.
4. The "delta" between position numbers, that should be equal to 1, equals to a number depending on **setOffscreenPageLimit**: it is 3 for default offscreen pages limit = 1, 5 for 2 ... 13 for 6.

Can anybody explain me why does this happen?

Some code:

In my case there are 720 pages and I set one of them to be the first shown page. The position numbers become wrong immediately after the first scroll from this page.

```
    final VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById (R.id.verticalviewpager);
    verticalViewPager.setAdapter(new myAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    verticalViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); 
    verticalViewPager.setCurrentItem(initialPosition); //initialPosition=532
```

Adapter:

```
public class myAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        Log.d("Position", String.valueOf(position));
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 720;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        return "PAGE" + String.valueOf(position);
    }

}
```

Fragment:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        Log.d("CurPosition", String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to use same library to get verticalview pager. I have not started yet. Have you succeed to achieve what you wanted? Could you help me as well if you did it?